# Spring Hibernate Mysql: how to get object for many-to-one, many-to-many, one-to-many

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

For the relationship of many-to-one, one-to-many or even many-to-many, how to get an object without the objects included on the other side?

Say a group of address and a group of people, the relationship would be many-to-many, what if i just wanne get a "people" without the concerned address?

**Classroom.java**

```
@Entity
public class Classroom {

public Classroom(){
}

public Classroom(long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "classroom_people", 
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "classroom_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "people_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private List<People> peoples = new ArrayList<>();

... 
// getter() and setter()
```

}

**People.java**

```
@Entity
public class People{

public People(){
}

public People(long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "peoples", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Classroom> classrooms = new ArrayList<>();

...
// getter() and setter()
```

}

By using hibernate, the table of Classroom, People and the join table classroom_people have been created automatically. Until now, everything is fine.

Then by using spring repository, I tried to fetch a people by passing the name, and return a JSON object.

What I hope to get is just a JSON including **people.id** and **people.name** but what I get is a JSON including one **people** and all the **classroom** in the Set, which includes all the concerning **peoples**.

SO I guess the problem is the List and List and what I should do is to create three tables: classroom, people and classroom_people, then store the relationship manually to join table. Then I can fetch a simple object without problem.

AM I right?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I use Spring Repository and findAllByName(), so the SQL is generated by spring. Just wonder whether this would be the source of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easily done with HQL if you keep the relationships bidirectional.
Something like:

```
String hql = "select addr.people from " + Address.class.getName() + " addr where addr.name(or some other attribute) = :addressName"
//set parameter "addressName"
```

EDIT:
Now you took a different example, but the above query applies the same, for example getting people from a classroom.

About your last note, getting a `People` by name will fetch only `People` instance, because the `@ManyToMany` `List` referencing classrooms is LAZY which means is not populated **until you call `people.getClassRooms()`**(if you have the session open it will load the empty list with another query)
You don't need to create the junction table yourselves, not for this purpose.

How do you know that `List<ClassRoom>` is populated when you fetch a `People`? Because from your mappings it looks OK, unless you're calling `people.getClassRooms()`

Comment: the relationship is bidirectional. I know what you mean, but that needs to search the table of **Address** and what I wanne do is to search directly the **people** table with people.name = "name". unfortunately my method falls into the loop of  **address** and **people** and return a JSON really long and meaningless.

Comment: I was explaining the more complex many-to-many relationship, you have to search on the junction table. But with Hibernate you don't need to do that, you can just select as I said and hibernate will generate the proper SQL joins and select from junction table.

Comment: what i used is a table for class, a table for people and a join table for the association. but every entity has a many-to-many relationship and a Set. So I wonder perhaps the problem is the Set?

Comment: What is the problem with my approach? Please include the entities and the annotations in the question so that things become more clear.

Comment: I add code source and explain my question. I think now my question is more like : how to create the join table, either by **joinTable** and Hibernate which is automatical, or an object **classroom_people** and**Table**.

Comment: thank you for your time, this is really kind. I add the db content and the result. So you can see, both people and classroom have been fetched.

Comment: How are you serializing it to JSON? you're most likely calling somewhere `people.getClassRooms();`.

Comment: I do nothing to convert to JSON. It is done by spring I think. So you suppose spring calls people.getClassrooms()?

Comment: that may be the reason. I will check the JSON converter and send you the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103657/discussion-between-isah-and-sprintboot).